# Trying to filter json object for a single value collection in Karate API Test Framework

Tags: json, api, karate

I have a JSON object here

- def response =
  """
  [
  {
  name: 'xyz',
  "jobs": [
  "JOB1"
  ],
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "progress": 100
  },
  {
  name: 'xyz1',
  "jobs": [
  "JOB2"
  ],
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "progress": 100
  }
  ]
  """

I want to get the json filtered using "jobs" and display like below

```
            {
                name: 'xyz1',
                "jobs": [
                    "JOB2"
                ],
                "status": "COMPLETED",
                "progress": 100
            }
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: sorry your question is not clear. what do you mean "filtered using jobs". have you read the documentation ? https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#jsonpath-filters

Comment: @PeterThomas

Example json:
{
{
"jobs": [
            "INSURANCE1"
        ],
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "progress": 100
},{
"jobs": [
            "INSURANCE2"
        ],
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "progress": 100
}
}

I need like this 

{
"jobs": [
            "INSURANCE2"
        ],
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "progress": 100
}

Comment: I still have no idea but I will be as vague in my answer. by the way that is not valid JSON

Comment: @PeterThomas, This is the Actual JSON

[
{
    "jobs": [
        "INSURANCE1"
    ],
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "progress": 100,
    "logDetails": [
        
    ],
    "websocket": true
},
{
    "jobs": [
        "INSURANCE2"
    ],
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "progress": 100,
    "logDetails": [
        
    ],
    "websocket": true
},
{
    "jobs": [
        "INSURANCE3"
    ],
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "progress": 100,
    "logDetails": [
        
    ],
    "websocket": true
}
]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
* def filtered = response.filter(x => x.jobs[0] == 'JOB2')
* print filtered
* def first = filtered[0]
```

Comment: Getting this error "Failed generating bytecode for <eval>:1" at the first line of code in Intellij execution. Could anyone please help me..?

Comment: @UdayKumar no, unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue